# How to change tint color on Apple Pay view

Tags: ios, applepay

Is there a way to change the tint color of the CANCEL button and the cells ARROW in the Apple Pay view? I tried the code below:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope—your app does not get any control over the appearance of the Apple Pay view. If you’d like a way to do that, you can [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com).